# Problema con rangos en expresión regular

Tags: regex

Estoy intentando realizar una expresión regular que valide el siguiente formato:

- sólo habrán números separados por comas o guión
- pueden haber intervalos de números (separados por guiones)
- los números deben ir del 1 al 31
- que el valor de la segunda parte sea mayor al de la primera (esto igual es más complejo, pero si es muy difícil lo descartaré)

Ejemplo de cadenas que consideraría válidas:

**4,31,2-22,8 

29,1-10,2-12,9**

Ejemplo de cadenas no válidas:

**4,31,2-22,8, 

29,1-10,-2-12-,9 

29,1-50,2-12,32**

La expresión regular que tengo hasta el momento es la siguiente:

```
((([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])(\-([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1]))?)
(\,(([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])(\-([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1]))?))*)
```

De momento esta expresión me coge bien el tema de los guiones y comas, pero no consigo que me coja bien los números de 10 a 31 y el tema del rango que el segundo valor sea mayor que el primero no se me ocurre cómo solventarlo
¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: No te aconsejo basarte en regexp para todas las comprobaciones. ¿Cómo comparas si es mayor un rango que un único número?

Comment: No se me ocurre como comprobar que la primera parte del rango sea menor a la segunda con una expresión regular, lo podría hacer mediante código pero era por ver si  se podía unificar en la expresión regular

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

```
^(?:(?:(?:\d-(?!3[2-9])[123]\d|1-[2-9]|2-[3-9]|3-[4-9]|4-[5-9]|5-[6-9]|6-[7-9]|7-[8-9]|8-9|(?:([1-3])0-\1[1-9]|([1-3])1-\2[2-9]|([1-3])2-\3[3-9]|([1-3])3-\4[4-9]|([1-3])4-\5[5-9]|([1-3])5-\6[6-9]|([1-3])6-\7[7-9]|([1-3])7-\8[8-9]|([1-3])8-\9[9])|1\d-2\d|[12]\d-3[01])|(?!3[2-9])[123]\d|[1-9])(?:,(?!$)|\b))+$
```

No es una expresión regular bonita ni intuitiva, pero debería hacer lo que necesitas.

Tienes una demo de la expresión regular [aquí](https://regex101.com/r/9utF1q/12/).

Y también una demo con javascript a continuación:

```js
const datosDePrueba = [
 '4,31,2-22,8'
,'29,1-10,2-12,9'
,'4,31,2-22,8,'
,'29,1-10,-2-12-,9'
,'29,1-50,2-12,32'
,'10-15'
,'22-23,11-22'
,'22-23,22-23'
,'22-23'
,'11-12'
,'5-6'
,'7-12'
,'12-13'
,'13-14,24-30'
,'22-23,22-23,11-12,5-6,10-15,21-29,30-31,28-31'
,'23-31'
,'23-30'
,'11-11'
,'13-12'
,'12-7'
,'23-34'
,'23-32'
,'44-22'
,'20-10'
,'20-3'
];

datosDePrueba.forEach(function(x) {
  console.log('El elemento ' + x + ' ' + (
    /^(?:(?:(?:\d-(?!3[2-9])[123]\d|1-[2-9]|2-[3-9]|3-[4-9]|4-[5-9]|5-[6-9]|6-[7-9]|7-[8-9]|8-9|(?:([1-3])0-\1[1-9]|([1-3])1-\2[2-9]|([1-3])2-\3[3-9]|([1-3])3-\4[4-9]|([1-3])4-\5[5-9]|([1-3])5-\6[6-9]|([1-3])6-\7[7-9]|([1-3])7-\8[8-9]|([1-3])8-\9[9])|1\d-2\d|[12]\d-3[01])|(?!3[2-9])[123]\d|[1-9])(?:,(?!$)|\b))+$/m.test(x)
    ? '' : '*NO* '
  ) + 'hace match');
});
```

Comentar que cuando la expresión regular se empieza a complicar, es mejor utilizar una expresión regular más sencilla añadiendo algo de código. Es mucho más fácil de mantener.

Aquí abajo pongo la misma expresión regular en formato extendido, con comentarios.

```
^
  (?: # Grupo para englobar toda la expresión regular para repetirla (+)
    (?: # Este grupo engloba números y rangos
      (?: # Opción 1: Rangos permitidos...
         \d-(?!3[2-9]) [123]\d # 1.a: válido si empieza por 1 dígito y luego 2
        |1-[2-9]|2-[3-9]|3-[4-9]|4-[5-9] # 1.b.*: Opciones posibles si empieza
        |5-[6-9]|6-[7-9]|7-[8-9]|8-9     #        por 1 dígito y sigue 1
        | (?: # 1.c.*: Opciones posibles para rango de 2 y 2 dígitos cuando el 
              #        primer dígito es el mismo: XY-XZ:
              # Capturamos el primer dígito para referenciarlo en la otra 
              # parte del rango
             ([1-3])0-\1[1-9]|([1-3])1-\2[2-9]|([1-3])2-\3[3-9]
            |([1-3])3-\4[4-9]|([1-3])4-\5[5-9]|([1-3])5-\6[6-9]
            |([1-3])6-\7[7-9]|([1-3])7-\8[8-9]|([1-3])8-\9[9]
          )
        |1\d-2\d|[12]\d-3[01] # 1.d.*: Opciones para rangos de 2 y 2 donde el 
                              #        primer dígito no coincide: XY-ZA
      )
      | (?!3[2-9]) [123]\d # Opción 2: Números simples de dos posiciones
                           #           No permitimos > 31
      | [1-9] # Opción 3: Número simple de una posición
    )
    (?:,(?!$)|\b) # Cada número/rango debe terminar con límite de palabra
                  # o con coma no precedida por fin de línea
  )+
$
```

Finalmente, si quieres algo más sencillo y no validar si la parte izquierda es menor que la derecha, podrías utilizar esta expresión regular, que es un poco más corta que la que proponías en el enunciado.

```
^(?!.*[4-9]\d|3[2-9]|\b0\b)(?:\d\d?(?:-\d\d?)?(?:,(?!$)|\b))+$
```

La idea es un poco distinta. En lugar de ir permitiendo solo lo que me interesa, aquí 'permitimos todo' (usamos `\d`) y utilizamos reglas para excluir los casos que no nos interesan.

Por cierto, comentar un par de cosas en la expresión regular del enunciado:

1. Los guiones `-` solo se deben escapar con contrabarra cuando están dentro de caracteres de clase y el guión no está al final. Por ejemplo, aquí se debe escapar si quieres especificar guion: `[A\-B]`, aquí no es necesario `[AB-]`. Y aquí tampoco: `A-B`
2. Si no se pretende capturar lo que hay dentro de los grupos, es mejor utilizar grupos sin captura `(?:)` en lugar de `()`
3. Tu expresión regular tenía un pequeño problema. Por ejemplo, si intentas validar `32` encontrará `2`. Podrías subsanarlo añadiendo `^` al inicio de tu expresión regular

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta @Julio funciona a la perfección

Comment: @Joacer Me alegra que te funcione. He añadido la explicación de la expresión regular y mientras lo hacía me he dado cuenta de un problema que tenía y que ya he arreglado. Si vas a utilizarla asegúrate de utilizar esta última versión

Comment: Muchísimas gracias @Julio, de esta forma queda todo muy bien explicado y espero que le pueda servir a muchas más personas.